# Sprite for list items

Tags: css, sprite

Good day
I am trying to use sprite of social media icons for a simple list.
Here is what I expect:

[image]

I have tried the below mentioned code but unfortunately,it shows nothing.
Can anyone tell me how to use it in a proper way?

```css
.sprite {
    background-image: url(img/spr.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
}
.soc1 {
    width: 37px;
    height: 37px;
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.soc2 {
    width: 37px;
    height: 37px;
    background-position: 0 -37px;
}

.soc3 {
    width: 37px;
    height: 37px;
    background-position: 0 -74px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="secondlist">
  <li class="secondlist_item">
    <a href="#" class="soc1" title="Facebook"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="secondlist_item">
    <a href="#" class="soc2" title="AskMe"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="secondlist_item">
    <a href="#" class="soc3" title="Twitter"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="secondlist_item">
    <a href="#" class="soc4" title="MySpace"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="secondlist_item">
    <a href="#" class="soc5" title="Feed"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Locally stored image not showing here. Could you give live link for image url.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/raeiX.png
here it is

Comment: `class="soc1"` will do nothing as you haven't actually loaded the sprite - try `class="sprite soc1"` - also, move width and height to sprite class as it's consistent with all other classes, so just use `soc1` etc to set position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments:

You need to load the sprite with the class so use e.g.

```
class="sprite soc1"
```

Change css to:

```
.sprite {
    background-image: url(img/spr.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    width: 37px;
    height: 37px;
}
.soc1 {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.soc2 {
    background-position: 0 -37px;
}

.soc3 {
    background-position: 0 -74px;
}
```

You're then just using e.g. `soc1` to set sprite position.